# Security concerns with users created for R scripts in SQL Server

Tags: windows, security, r, ms-sql

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497177/too-many-sql-server-users) and [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20ab5497-e64a-47f2-b90f-a1dfb006cc58/using-r-in-windows-10-creates-too-many-local-user-accounts?forum=sqlgetstarted), installing R with a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 installation (possibly other versions) creates 20 users in the SQLRUserGroup. As explained in the links, these user accounts are all made by design in order to allow execution of multiple R scripts.

However, I cannot find any relevant security information when it comes to these accounts. Adding 20 logins sounds like a way to increase the attack surface of my system for an intruder to exploit.

**Concerns:**
What are the security-related implications of having these users exist on my computer? Does this create a security hole if someone knows how the passwords for these users are generated/stored (or if the passwords are just weak to begin with)?

Comment: You might get better answer in the security.stackexchange site...

Comment: If an intruder has physical access to your machine then all bets are off.  You should verify the SQLRUserGroup has only the permissions required for the user to run the script.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I agree from an absolute standpoint that all bets are off after physical access, but I don't think that voids any attempts at mitigation. Also, it isn't necessarily about physical access. Maybe someone allowed remote access (RDP, for example) configuration, and isn't aware that these accounts are possibly vulnerable. Hardening always good.

If SuperUser was the inappropriate place for this and doesn't produce answers, I'll gladly have it moved to Security, but I figured this would be something more superuser-esque because it's about services provided with SQL Server.

Comment: Why are you allowing those users, to access your system, remotely?  They don't need that permission.  If you are worried security concerns surrounding RDP access, unless you need it, disable it entirely.

Comment: 100% agree that would ideal.

Comment: (Ran out of edit time) To clarify, this isn't just about _me_, it's about mitigating access (increasing the effort it would take to compromise something, like locking a door despite locksmiths existing), for anyone that might install these users without knowing possible ramifications (maybe other computers aren't as hardened as mine, so important notes or mitigation steps should be added to anyone that chooses to install these users).

Comment: @Talset If you want to mitigate security vulnerabilities, then limit the attack surface by disabling all features, functions, services, etc. that are not needed on the machine that you have a security concern about actually. So in this case, if SQL Server is super important and critical to your business, etc. then simply have it installed on its own dedicated OS and only allow access to it remotely by scripts (whatever they are) and do not install other things onto the same OS as the SQL Server. This is standard practice 101 from a security perspective.

Comment: So RDP, R scripts, etc. on the SQL Server is not a good idea if you have security concerns about this SQL Server and it's critical to your environment. Only allow your admins access to the physical server even remotely via RDP and all all others and all other processes, scripts, etc. access remotely only and no OS level access. Utilize stored procedures where possible as well and execute SPs if you want the server to do the heavy processing. There's many ways to skin a cat including when you want to be security conscious.